# Recover deleted data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I retrieve deleted data from a table in an SQL Server Database with full recovery model?

Comment: Restore a backup?

Comment: @msaleh These tutorials might help you in different scenario's :
1. [Recover Deleted Data From SQL Table Using Transaction Log and LSNs](https://dzone.com/articles/recover-deleted-data-from-sql-table-using-transact)
2. [By Consdiering different scenrios](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-sql-server-data-from-delete-truncate-drop/)

Answer (score 0):

To Recover the deleted SQL Data first repair the error that caused the error. 
Open DB Browse for your Database 
Click on Execute SQL tab
In the console type the command 'PRAGMA integrity_Check' and click on the Play button
Once it is known the Database is in a consistent state run the command DBCC DBREPAIR to run repair DB files
Rebuild the database with REPAIR_REBUILD option
Now you can easily recover the files in SQL Database.
[Recover deleted database in SQL](https://www.filerepairtools.com/tips/resolving-sql-database-error-5243-5242/) and get your files back.